# Получить данные из файла и впихнуть в динам массив в программе

Tags: delphi, файлы

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить данные из файла (файл типизирован как и массив - списком). А то не могу понять, как:

> ```
> type
>   fullname = record
>     surname:string[255];
>     name:   string[255];
>     midname:string[255];
>   end;
> type
>   fulldate = record
>     day:  integer;
>     month:integer;
>     year: integer;
>   end;
> type
>   person = record
>     fio:   fullname;
>     adress:string[255];
>     born:  fulldate;
>     brain: double;
>   end;
> type
> TArr = array of person;
> var
>   f1:File of person;
>   student : TArr;
>   x:integer;
> Procedure LoadInfo(var stud:TArr);
> var
>   filename:string;
>   i:integer;
> begin
>   filename:=('H:\2 sem\progr\lab_works\Laba3\studMain.bin');
>   AssignFile(f1,filename);
>   Reset(f1);
>   i:=0;
>   while not Eof(f1) do
>   begin
>     i:=i+1;
>     stud[i]:=Read(f1,stud[i]);//тут как-то по-другому нужно, а вот как - не знаю(
>   end;
>   CloseFile(f1);
> end;
> ```
>
> //....

Comment: Просто `Read(f1,stud[i]);`, только длину массива не забывайте увеличивать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Элементы динамических массивов нумеруются с нуля.
2. Сколько элементов Вашем массиве? Что будет если в файле окажется больше записей, чем в массиве?

   ```
   SetLength(stud, FileSize(f1));
   while (not Eof(f1)) and (i < Length(stud)) do
   begin
     Read(f1, stud[i]);
     i:=i+1;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Массив динамический, т.е. кол-во эл-ов меняется в зависимости от наших действий. Если в файле будет больше записей, чем в массиве, то они, вероятно, просто не попадут в массив, верно?

Comment: Количество элементов меняется тогда, когда мы его меняем (`SetLength`). По вашему коду нигде не учитывался размер массива, по-этому я и спросил. Это были наводящие вопросы :) Если не проверять размер массива и читать пока не закончится файл, то можно выйти за пределы массива.